# Does jQuery 2.x support Internet Explorer 11 Enterprise Mode?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, jquery-2.0

We are currently starting development of a new enterprise intranet framework.

In the conceptual phase the question arose, whether we can incorporate the latest version of jQuery 2.x, bearing in mind that IE11 might run in Enterprise Mode.

Enterprise Mode means IE8-compatibility, so does this impose jQuery 2.x will not support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.
According to [jQuery Forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/does-jquery-2-x-support-ie11-enterprise-mode/), this IE11 enterprise mode is not supported.
If necessary, one should stick to the latest jQuery 1.11.x.